# Get vector's contents from class to another C++ OOP

Tags: c++, oop, vector, polymorphism

I have a file in which I create a vector. In this file I add content to the vector. I then want to be able to edit/remove contents from the vector in a different file's class. I thought inheriting would do the trick but it doesn't copy the contents. Simplified pseudo:

```
// parentFile.h

class parentFile {
public:
    void addPerson();
    vector <Income> person_; // Creating vector that gets variables from Income class
};

// parentFile.cpp

void parentFile::addPerson() {  // Add a person to the vector
    Income arg; 
    arg.askInfo();   // Asks string name, last name, float salary
    person_.push_back(arg);    // Adding contents to vector
}


// childFile.h

class childFile : public parentFile {
public:
    void countPersons();
};

// childFile.cpp

void childFile::countPersons()  {  // I need the vector's contents here for editing.
    cout << person_.size() << endl;  // Teste case: person_ vector is empty here. 
}
```

tl;dr problem: Contents added to vector person_; are not recognized anymore in childFile. I've been fiddling around with trying to copy the vector/polymorph/virtual functions etc. but I haven't made any progress.

Comment: Value of variables defined in the parent class are not accessible in the child class. Only the member is available and not its contents.

Comment: try to re-think your approach.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee That makes zero sense. The member *and* its contents are available, there aren't two variables with the same name. And the child class can access the member of its parent class given the correct access rights.

Comment: Also, I [cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/g/vgGaXL). Scroll down the assembly and you will see that `1` is returned. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: *Simplified pseudo:* -- No, the actual code please.

Comment: This is the actual full code. I commented the lines that are important. I fugred the code above is more clear as that's the base of the problem.
https://pastebin.com/V8QvfMT4

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that you created two objects, one instance of `parentFile` and one instance of `childFile`, added the elements to the `parentFile`, and then examined the `childFile`.

Comment: I can't speak Finnish, so I can't found the corresponding piece of code for `void parentFile::addPerson()` in the full code but if it is written as in the pseudo, in the method `Income arg` must be initialized with a costructor or copying an existing `Income` object, otherwise it causes an error.